# Mongodb maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis does not work

Tags: mongodb, transactions

Environment: Windows, mongodb 5.0, single node replicaset.

in mongod.cfg

```
setParameter:
  maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis: 3000
```

Create DB and collection test with one object:

```
objId = ObjectId("613233675a5ea6722c960051");
db.test.insert({_id: objId, item: "A"});
```

Open 2 mongo shell windows to create 2 concurrent transactions:
Window 1:

```
session = db.getMongo().startSession( { readPreference: { mode: "primary" } } );
coll = session.getDatabase(dbName).getCollection("test");
session.startTransaction( { readConcern: { level: "local" }, writeConcern: { w: "majority" } } );
coll.updateOne({_id: objId}, { $set: {item: "B"}})
```

Window 2:

```
session = db.getMongo().startSession( { readPreference: { mode: "primary" } } );
coll = session.getDatabase(dbName).getCollection("test");
session.startTransaction( { readConcern: { level: "local" }, writeConcern: { w: "majority" } } );
coll.updateOne({_id: objId}, { $set: {item: "C"}})
```

Second update fails immediately without waiting for 3 seconds:

```
WriteCommandError({
        "errorLabels" : [
                "TransientTransactionError"
        ],
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.",
        "code" : 112,
        "codeName" : "WriteConflict",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1632429457, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1632429457, 1)
})
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug in mongodb?

Comment: It is not directly related to original scenario, but if in the window 2 I execute update WITHOUT transaction, it blocks and waits, probably indefinitely for transaction in window 1 to complete.

Comment: My summary of the issue is: mongodb transactions behave differently than transactions in majority of RDBMSes. Mongo transaction does not wait for lock to be released, it fails immediately if it encounters document locked by another transaction. Thus mongodb transactions cannot be used in high concurrency scenarios like most people used to in a RDBMS world.

Comment: I remember long time ago I talked to mongodb support about lack of transactions in mongodb, and the answer was: you do not need transactions, redesign your DB. 
Now the story repeats: mondodb says you do not need transactions waiting for the lock to be released, it's ok to fail and retry.
No it's not :)

Answer (score 1):

That is not how `maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis` works, your problem is related to write conflicts and nothing else. Before trying to acquire a lock, MongoDB checks whether other transactions are updating the target document. If it is the case, then it does not need to ask for a lock on the document because it knows in advance that eventually, when both transactions commit, a write conflict is going to occur.

How to solve a write conflict? The transaction is aborted and retried (in case of retryable writes) hoping that it can now acquire a snapshot that includes the changes made by the first transaction, that must have commit in the meanwhile.

So, how to solve it? You really cannot because the snapshot isolation is an optimistic MVCC strategy. If your transactions are going to conflict with each other and you know it, the only thing you can do is to run them sequentially. The general rule is: you cannot have two ongoing transactions that are trying to change the same document.

About the comment:

> It is not directly related to original scenario, but if in the window 2 I execute update WITHOUT transaction, it blocks and waits, probably indefinitely for transaction in window 1 to complete.

This is a different type of conflict, called transaction/operation conflict. In this case the non-transactional operation cannot update the document because it is locked by the transaction until it commits. The strategy used by MongoDB here is to retry the non-transactional operation with exponential backoff logic until the `MaxTimeMS` timeout elapsed (if set, otherwise there is an internal timeout that for the NodeJS driver is set to 2 minutes for example, but it is an implementation detail of course).

These topics are quite complex, if you want to learn more about them, my advice is to read [this](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/tree/main/doc#snapshot-isolation) paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, @Marco Luzzara, and for the detailed report. I am still confused on how maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis can possibly be used, what is the scenario? Locking document can be done only by write operation within transaction. But how another transaction can try to acquire that lock and wait for maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis is that another write operation will be conflicting with the first operation that holds the lock?
I tried to modify my test to update different fields in the document, item2 instead of item to avoid writeConflict, but fails.

Comment: I have not found much about `maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis` and the report just mentions it, but I guess there are some situations where a document cannot be locked not only because it is part of a different transaction. For example, you could have an aggregation pipeline that operates on a document and it takes a lot of time for whatever reason. In sharded cluster you have also chunk migrations that prevents the locking of moving documents (and in certain cases they make the transaction fails directly).